# restriction of a formula with matrix inverse multiplied by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, proof-theory, bayesian-probability

I'm trying to reproduce a proof from [this paper](https://aaai.org/ojs/index.php/AAAI/article/view/4793) but I'm stuck in one point (Lemma 6). The general subject is bayesian model for multi-armed bandit problem solved with Thompson sampling.

I think I don't know any properties / tricks from linear algebra that can be useful here. Maybe you can help?

First there are a couple of coefficients:

- $\sigma_1 > 0, \sigma_2 > 0, \sigma_3>0$
- $ N $ number of possible vectors of features (arms)
- $ d $ dimentionality of vectors of features
- $x_i \in R^d,  i \in \{1, 2, ... N\}$ - vectors of features
- $ T $ number of time steps
- $ t \in {1, 2, ..T} $ a selected moment in time
- $ n_{i,t} $ - how many times we observed vector $x_i$ up to time t - we know that $ \sum_{i=1}^{N} n_{i,t} = t$ it's a random number (but depend on the algorithm)

$$
A_t = \frac{1}{\sigma_3^2} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{n_{i,t}}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 * n_{i,t}} * x_i * x_i^T
$$

We need to restrict somehow for all t:
$$
\sqrt{x_i^T * A_t^{-1} x_i}
$$

or restrict

$$
\sum_{t=1}^{T} \sqrt{x_i^T * A_t^{-1} x_i}
$$

in terms of  $\sigma_1 > 0, \sigma_2 > 0, N, d, T$. Apparently  $\sigma_3$ is not present in the results.

**Do you think you can give me some tips what can we used here or how to proceed?**
It's possible that we need some more reasonable assumptions that are not stated in the paper directly. (for example about $x_i$). 
It's possible that the whole proof should be approached differently. Any comments are welcome

Comment: The paper says: "The detailed proof is in supplementary materials." Did you find the proof there?

Comment: It's not possible to obtain these materials anywhere - I searched the internet, wrote to authors and someone from AAI - no one has replied to me.